# How can I vary part of a formula argument when wrapping models in tidyeval?

Tags: r, tidyeval

As far as I have seen there are two ways of dealing with formula arguments when you want to make functions that wrap models. You can paste string versions of formula together:

```r
library(tidyverse)
run_model1 <- function(df, dep_str, ...){
  groupers <- enquos(...)
  formula <- dep_str %>% str_c("~ cty") %>% as.formula()
  df %>%
    group_by(!!!groupers) %>%
    do(model = lm(formula, data = .))
}
```

or you can quote the whole formula:

```r
run_model2 <- function(df, formula, ...){
  groupers <- enquos(...)
  formula <- enexpr(formula)
  df %>%
    group_by(!!!groupers) %>%
    do(model = lm(!!formula, data = .))
}
```

both of which do in fact allow me to get grouped models while varying a variable in the formula.

```r
run_model1(mpg, "hwy", cyl)
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>     cyl model   
#> * <int> <list>  
#> 1     4 <S3: lm>
#> 2     5 <S3: lm>
#> 3     6 <S3: lm>
#> 4     8 <S3: lm>
run_model2(mpg, hwy ~ cty, cyl)
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>     cyl model   
#> * <int> <list>  
#> 1     4 <S3: lm>
#> 2     5 <S3: lm>
#> 3     6 <S3: lm>
#> 4     8 <S3: lm>
```

However, the first requires an awkward mixing of quoted and unquoted arguments and especially does not work well if I want to access the symbol version for use later. The second forces me to supply the entire formula every time, when I'd rather only supply one part.

Basically, how can I get a function that would take arguments like this?

```r
run_model3(mpg, hwy, cyl)
```

Comment: You are comparing against `cty` in these examples, how would this be expected to behave outside those cases? Is there a reason you cannot use `.` formula notation to indicate all others

Comment: I currently do not need it to compare against anything other than `cty` (because I will be running this after a function that creates `cty`). But I would assume that if I can write `run_model3` as given it would not be hard to have a predictor variable argument as well. I do need to compare to specific known columns (i.e. not using `.`) but they do not need to be arguments.

Comment: I've given it a go - seems to behave as I understand you are expecting - let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ensym()` should let you capture a symbol provided to the function.

> `ensym()` and `ensyms()` are variants of `enexpr()` and `enexprs()` that check
>   the captured expression is either a string (which they convert to
>   symbol) or a symbol. If anything else is supplied they throw an error.

[source](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html)

```
run_model3 <- function (df, dep_str, ...) {
  dep_str <- ensym(dep_str)
  groupers <- enquos(...)
  formula <- dep_str %>% str_c("~ cty") %>% as.formula()
  df %>%
    group_by(!!!groupers) %>%
    do(model = lm(formula, data = .))
}
```

---

```
> run_model3(mpg, hwy, cyl)
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 2
    cyl model   
* <int> <list>  
1     4 <S3: lm>
2     5 <S3: lm>
3     6 <S3: lm>
4     8 <S3: lm>
```

And based off the quote before we can even use the current method of `run_model1`:

```
> run_model3(mpg, "hwy", cyl)
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 2
    cyl model   
* <int> <list>  
1     4 <S3: lm>
2     5 <S3: lm>
3     6 <S3: lm>
4     8 <S3: lm>
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but the part that is the most surprising to me is that supplying a bare symbol to `str_c` works as expected. Do you have any insight on that?

Comment: Yeah, so if you read the code for `str_c` it is a wrapper of `stri_c` which has its documentation mention "character vectors (or objects coercible to character vectors) which corresponding elements are to be concatenated" for the `...` arg. Symbols are therefore implied to be coercible.